# Downgrade java from version 8 to 7

Tags: java, version, downgrade

I have installed Java 1.8 from Oracle on Ubuntu because I though it would be best, newest version compatible with previous ones. But it is not.
`javac` 1.8 produces bytecode runnable only on the java-8-oracle, scala does not run.

Before upgrade I was using java-7-openjdk, everything was fine. While
I can choose my older virtual machine using `sudo update-alternatives --config java`, but I also need to be able to choose older compiler.
How can I do this?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_jdk.html#A1096903

Answer (score 4):

Use the `-target` flag to generate bytecode for earlier version. E.g. `javac -target 1.5 FooBar.java`.

There's no need to downgrade.

Comment: Your suggestion gives "javac: target release 1.7 conflicts with default source release 1.8".

Comment: Then modify the source compatibility as well with `-source 1.7`.

Comment: Better, but I still get "warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7". But at least I can launch programs now, thanks.

Comment: Note that this won't prevent you from using APIs only available in Java SE 8. You would need some additional steps: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javac.html#BHCIJIEG
For this reason I recommend to use the JDK you're actually targeting.

Answer (score 1):

At least for Oracle's JDK (not sure about OpenJDK): install either the `oracle-java7-set-default` or the `oracle-java8-set-default` package, depending on which java version you want to be the default on your system.

You can get it from: http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu (including the actual Oracle JDKs) See: https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/java

Alternatively you could set the PATH and JAVA_HOME environment variables e.g. in /etc/environment

That said, when you compile you could specify the source and target level to 1.7, which would generate Java SE 7 compatible bytecode also when using JDK 8. But note it won't check if you're using some API not available in Java SE 7.

For this reason I recommend to use always the JDK version you target rather than doing some cross-compiling (which would need [some additional extra steps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javac.html#BHCIJIEG) to do it right).

Note however that you can install several JDK versions on your systems. IDEs usually let you choose which one you want to use during development.

Answer (score 1):

1. Set up `java_home` environment variable to older version and compile Java files using it. Make sure that `java.exe` in path variable is of earlier version.
2. Use `-target` flag while compiling.