# How to Downgrade java version in centos?

Tags: java, centos, installation, downgrade, javapns

I have installed java in Centos 6.7 with version:

```
java -version
java version "1.6.0_38"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.10) (rhel-1.13.10.0.el6_7-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

I want to Downgrade the java version to

```
java -version
java version "1.6.0_17"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.7.10) (rhel-1.20.b17.el5-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0-b16, mixed mode)
```

How to achieve this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Downgrade java from version 8 to 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23322024/downgrade-java-from-version-8-to-7)

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use an older build?

Comment: Yes it is due to JVM Bugs encountered while Push Notifications:

http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8013809

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use different java version to run two programs](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178875/use-different-java-version-to-run-two-programs)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install the version you need ,

```
# cd /<place you want java installed>/
# wget --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2F; oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/<version>/jdk-<version>-linux-x64.tar.gz"

# tar xzf jdk-<version>-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

Install Java with alternatives,

```
# cd /<place java install>/jdk1.6.0_17/
# alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk1.6.0_17/bin/java 2
# alternatives --config java
```

Then select the version want

```
There are 2 programs which provide 'java'.

Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
* + 1           /opt/jdk1.6.0_38/bin/java
2           /opt/jdk1.6.0_17/bin/java

Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number:
```

Enter 2

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading and installing the specific version from Java downloads, then change the Java home path.

Comment: Somewhat OK, Can u please send me the steps.